# How to make a Python code execute on GPU and not CPU

Tags: python, python-3.x, gpu, image-preprocessing

I am doing some image pre-processing using Python 3. As I know the code is executed on CPU for which the process is a little bit slow, its a good idea to make it run on GPU for the faster process because GPU can do graph operation much faster than CPU. Is there a way to make it run on GPU without using a library?

Please note that it is required to make it like a GPU version of Keras or TensorFlow.

Comment: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/07/11/compiling-opencv-with-cuda-support/

Comment: It is pretty rare that image processing be expensive for a single image, it is either for a lot of images or for a very big image.  GPUs are memory bound, therefore processing a lot of images or very big images will not improve by using GPUs, the memory copying between RAM and GPU will eat away any improvement.  Is it really the processing expensive or it is amount of images?  (i.e. you're processing more than a single image)

Comment: If time permits, watch [this GPU vs CPU video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lGmPy8xpT4E)

Answer (score 1):

You may apply [Wolfram Language](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/) to your project. There is a free [Wolfram Engine](https://www.wolfram.com/developer/) for developers and with the [Wolfram Client Library for Python](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/WolframClientForPython/) you can use these functions in Python.

Either the [`CUDALink` Overview](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/CUDALink/tutorial/Overview.html) and [`CUDALink` Guide](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/CUDALink/guide/CUDALink.html) or the [`OpenCLLink` Overview](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/OpenCLLink/tutorial/Overview.html) and [`OpenCLLink` Guide](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/OpenCLLink/guide/OpenCLLink.html) will enable you to run code on your GPU.  However, the `CUDALink` guide image process functions built-in so perhaps best to start there for your project.

```
from wolframclient.evaluation import WolframLanguageSession
from wolframclient.language import wl, wlexpr
```

Start the Wolfram session.

```
wolfSession = WolframLanguageSession()
```

The CUDA package is included with the Wolfram Engine but has to be explicitly loaded.

```
wolfSession.evaluate(wl.Needs('CUDALink`'))
```

Then you can check if the engine has located one or more compatible GPUs with [`CUDAQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/CUDALink/ref/CUDAQ.html).

```
print(wolfSession.evaluate(wl.CUDALink.CUDAQ()))
```

> ```
> True
> ```

*There is a one-time download of CUDA binaries when `CUDAQ` is evaluated. You can make your first call directly in the kernel to track the one-time download instead of first calling through Python. Run `woframscript` in the terminal and evaluate the `Needs` and `CUDAQ` functions at the input prompt.*

> [image]

Detailed information can be returned with [`CUDAInformation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/CUDALink/ref/CUDAInformation.html).

```
print(wolfSession.evaluate(wl.CUDALink.CUDAInformation(1,'Core Count')))
```

> ```
> 160
> ```

Grab an image for some CUDA image function examples.

```
imgWolfram=wolfSession.evaluate(
    wl.Rasterize(
        wl.Import('https://i2.wp.com/oemscorp.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/wolfram-language-logo.png'),
        'Image'
    )
);
```

The image can be [`Export`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Export.html)ed in one of the supported [Raster Image Formats](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/RasterImageFormats.html) or [Vector Graphics Formats](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/VectorGraphicsFormats.html).

```
wolfSession.evaluate(
    wl.Export(
        '<path with image filename>', 
        imgWolfram
        )
    )
)
```

> [image: Wolfram Language logo]

A few example CUDA image functions include

- [`CUDAImageConvolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/CUDALink/ref/CUDAImageConvolve.html)

  ```
  wolfSession.evaluate(
      wl.Export(
          '<path with image filename>', 
          wl.CUDALink.CUDAImageConvolve(imgWolfram,  [[-1,0,1],[-2,0,2],[-1,0,1]])
      )
  )
  ```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

- [`CUDAErosion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/CUDALink/ref/CUDAErosion.html)

  ```
  wolfSession.evaluate(
      wl.Export(
          '<path with image filename>', 
          wl.CUDALink.CUDAErosion(imgWolfram,6)
      )
  )
  ```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

- [`CUDAOpening`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/CUDALink/ref/CUDAOpening.html)

  ```
  wolfSession.evaluate(
      wl.Export(
          '<path with image filename>', 
          wl.CUDALink.CUDAOpening(imgWolfram,6)
      )
  )
  ```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Terminate the Wolfram session.

```
wolfSession.terminate()
```

Since you have processing many image files you would get slightly better performance by processing directly in [wolfram script](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/program/wolframscript.html) with the Wolfram Engine rather than by calling the engine from Python.

Hope this helps.